# How to include license file in setup.py script?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have written a Python extension module in C++.
I plan to distribute the module with setuptools.
There will be binary distributions for 32- and 64-bit Windows (built with `setup.py bdist_egg`) and a source distribution for UNIX-like platforms (built with `setup.py sdist`).

I plan to license the module under the BSD license.
In my source tree, the file LICENSE.txt is in the top folder along with setup.py.
How should I include it in the installation package?

I tried the following setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from glob import glob

setup(
    name = 'Foo',
    version = '0.1.0',
    ext_modules = [Extension('Foo', glob('Source/*.cpp'))],
    package_data = {'': ['LICENSE.txt']}
)
```

It did not work, the license file is not included in the installation package.
Maybe because the setup.py file does not define any packages,
only a single extension module.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 24):

Write a `setup.cfg` file and in there specify:

```
[metadata]
license_files = LICENSE.txt
```

For this to work it seems like wheel is required to be installed. That is:

```sh
pip install wheel
```

If you have `wheel` already installed and it doesn't work, try to update it:

```sh
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

Then when installing the package via `pip install <path>` the LICENSE file gets included.

Comment: @user Yea, I guess it only does that for generated wheel file i.e. when you run: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`

https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#including-the-license-in-the-generated-wheel-file

Comment: Works for me, for both wheels and sdists.

Comment: @limonik With latest wheel looks like the license_file option has been deprecated. Refer to documentation here: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#including-license-files-in-the-generated-wheel-file

And use option "license_files =" instead. If this works for you I'll update my answer.

Comment: **TIP:** the new `license_files` metadata works only for _wheels_ - not _sdists_ - while the now deprecated `license_file` worked for both.  Use `MANIFEST.in` to control _sdist_ contents alone.

Comment: With respect to `setuptools`, the `license_file` key is [very much *not* deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/70b3ec0bf0f61d6b7de1beff4bad4b845d836100/setuptools/command/sdist.py#L223). `setuptools` continues to transparently support both the `license_file` *and* `license_files` keys without complaint. Only the `wheel` package unilaterally deprecated the `license_file` key – by, of course, replacing that key with an even less functional key. Consider either defining both (*yes, this is potato*) or only defining the `license_file` key (i.e., ignore `wheel`). `</picard_facepalm>`

Comment: **Note:** `setuptools` itself [only defines the `license_file` key in its `setup.cfg`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/53c284b325959a6fd177e9d37d8b5dd5824db2b3/setup.cfg#L25). It doesn't get any more non-deprecated than that, folks. **tl;dr:** just use `license_file`.

Comment: as of 2022, `license_file` is [deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/fbe659b74cbccbb095dd469a15324eb73285b714/docs/references/keywords.rst)

Answer (score 19):

[Since `setuptools` 42.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v42-0-0) you can use the `license_files` key to specify a list of license files to be included into a distribution. [Since version 56.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v56-0-0) it supports [pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and defaults to `('LICEN[CS]E*', 'COPYING*', 'NOTICE*', 'AUTHORS*')`.

Note that due to [implementation](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v42.0.0/setuptools/command/sdist.py#L201-L231) [details](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v42.0.0/setuptools/dist.py#L447-L462) there's actually no need to put this key into `setup.cfg` file (as another answer suggests). You could supply it as an argument to `setup()` function instead:
<sup>(documentation was unclear on this at the time of writing)</sup>

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    license_files = ('LICENSE.txt',),
    ...
)
```

Also note that while these files will be *included* in both binary (wheel) and source distributions, they won't be *installed* with your package from [`setup.py`-style](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#source-trees) source distribution if the user doesn't have a `wheel` package installed!
To ensure the license files will be installed along with your package you need to make some additional modifications to your setup script:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.egg_info import egg_info


class egg_info_ex(egg_info):
    """Includes license file into `.egg-info` folder."""

    def run(self):
        # don't duplicate license into `.egg-info` when building a distribution
        if not self.distribution.have_run.get('install', True):
            # `install` command is in progress, copy license
            self.mkpath(self.egg_info)
            self.copy_file('LICENSE.txt', self.egg_info)

        egg_info.run(self)


setup(
    ...
    license_files = ('LICENSE.txt',),
    cmdclass = {'egg_info': egg_info_ex},
    ...
)
```

If your project is a [`pyproject.toml`-style project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472800/11725753) and you think it will be installed by PEP 517-compatible frontend (e.g. `pip>=19`), a wheel will be forcibly built from your sources and the license files will be installed into `.dist-info` folder automatically.

[Since version 61.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v61-0-0) you could [specify project metadata and other configuration options in `pyproject.toml` file](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using a METADATA.in file, the license can be included both the source package and wheels automatically:

*METADATA.in*

`include README.md
include COPYING`

Check out an example here:
https://github.com/node40/smsh

Comment: your project doesn't have a MANIFEST.in file :)

Comment: I fixed the answer. The file is 'METADATA.in'.

Comment: The file needs to be named [`MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) to work. I expect puttinga  `METADATA.in` filename instead would just do a whole not of **nothing**.

Answer (score -1):

New setuptools (40.x) allows metadata, including license, to be stored in the [setup.cfg's "metadata" section](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files). If you use older setuptools you could provide license using the "license" named argument in your setup():

```
def read_text(file_name: str):
    return open(os.path.join(base_path, file_name)).read()


setup(
    name = 'Foo',
    version = '0.1.0',
    ext_modules = [Extension('Foo', glob('Source/*.cpp'))],
    # package_data = {'': ['LICENSE.txt']}
    license=read_text("LICENSE.txt")
)
```

Comment: This setup.py construct is bad because it will not create a package that uploads valid to PyPI. The `license` field expects a single line description (i.e. the license name), not multiline text from a file

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1390

Comment: I updated the example to fix ^ (wasn't able to edit my first comment)

Answer (score -1):

You have to move the LICENSE.txt file into the package directory for your project. It cannot reside the top level. Python directories get deployed, not the deployment artifact. If you create a python package, that package actually contains a number of subpackages. Each subpackage must contain ALL the files relevant to deployment.

Do not use `data_files` as it will actually distribute the files as a separate package. (I've heard `package_files` works, but I have yet to see a working example to do this).

Answer (score -5):

For example:

```
setup(
    ...
    license="ZPL",
    classifiers=[
        ...
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Zope Public License',
        ...
        ],
     ...)
```

additionally you can insert your licence text into 'long_description':

```
setup(
    ...
    long_description="Package description. \nLicense Text",
    ...)
```

Comment: How does that include a license _file_ anywhere?