# What is pyproject.toml file for?

Tags: python, pip, packaging, pyproject.toml

#### Background

I was about to try Python package downloaded from GitHub, and realized that it did not have a `setup.py`, so I could not install it with

```
pip install -e <folder>
```

Instead, the package had a **`pyproject.toml`** file which seems to have very similar entries as the `setup.py` usually has.

#### What I found

Googling lead me into [PEP-518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) and it gives some critique to `setup.py` in [Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#rationale) section. However, it does not clearly tell that usage of `setup.py` should be avoided, or that `pyproject.toml` would as such completely replace `setup.py`.

#### Questions

Is the `pyproject.toml` something that is used to replace `setup.py`? Or should a package come with both, a `pyproject.toml` and a `setup.py`?
How would one install a project with `pyproject.toml` in an editable state?

Comment: See [PEP-518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

Comment: Thanks, @KlausD, that was in the top Google results but the PEP-518 did not take stance on should developers avoid using `setup.py`, and how to install the packages in editable state, if `setup.py` is not used, etc.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

#### What is it for?

Currently there are multiple packaging tools being popular in Python community and while `setuptools` still seems to be prevalent it's not a de facto standard anymore. This situation creates a number of hassles for both end users and developers:

1. For `setuptools`-based packages installation from source / build of a distribution can fail if one doesn't have `setuptools` installed;
2. `pip` doesn't support the installation of packages based on other packaging tools from source, so these tools had to generate a `setup.py` file to produce a compatible package. To build a distribution package one has to install the packaging tool first and then use tool-specific commands;
3. If package author decides to change the packaging tool, workflows must be changed as well to use different tool-specific commands.

`pyproject.toml` is a new configuration file introduced by [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) and [PEP 518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) to solve these problems:

> ... think of the (rough) steps required to produce a built artifact for a project:
>
> 1. The source checkout of the project.
> 2. Installation of the build system.
> 3. Execute the build system.
>
> This PEP [518] covers step #2. [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) covers step #3 ...

Any tool can also extend this file with its own section (table) to accept tool-specific options, but it's up to them and not required.

[PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/) suggests using `pyproject.toml` to specify package core metadata in static, tool-agnostic way. Which backends currently support this is shown in the following table:

| [`enscons`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#enscons) | [`flit_core`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#flit) | [`hatchling`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#hatch) | [`pdm-pep517`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#pdm) | [`poetry-core`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#poetry) | [`setuptools`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#easy-install) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Supports] [0.26.0+](https://github.com/dholth/enscons/blob/master/CHANGES#:%7E:text=Support%20PEP%20621%20metadata) | [image: Supports] [3.2+](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#version-3-3) | [image: Supports] [0.3+](https://github.com/pypa/hatch/commit/eef7d0c#diff-846792860efe35ffaa63db526fa381c4f16f2caaa482ef3a8886e62d3454f5ce) | [image: Supports] [0.3.0+](https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm-pep517/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-v030-2020-12-21) | [image: Doesn't support] [Issue #3332](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3332) | [image: Supports] [61.0.0+](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v61-0-0) |

#### Does it replace `setup.py`?

For `setuptools`-based packages `pyproject.toml` is not strictly meant to replace `setup.py`, but rather to ensure its correct execution if it's still needed. For other packaging tools – yes, it is:

> Where the `build-backend` key exists, this takes precedence and the source tree follows the format and conventions of the specified backend (as such no `setup.py` is needed **unless the backend requires it**). Projects may still wish to include a `setup.py` for compatibility with tools that do not use this spec.

#### How to install a package in editable mode?

Originally "editable install" was a `setuptools`-specific feature and as such it was not supported by PEP 517. Later on [PEP 660](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/) extended this concept to packages using `pyproject.toml`.

There are two possible conditions for installing a package in editable mode using `pip`:

- **Modern:**
  Both the frontend (`pip`) and a backend must support PEP 660.
  `pip` supports it [since version 21.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/news/#v21-3);
- **Legacy:**
  Packaging tool must provide a `setup.py` file which supports the `develop` command.
  [Since version 21.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/news/#v21-1) `pip` can also install packages using only `setup.cfg` file in editable mode.

The following table describes the support of editable installs by various backends:

| [`enscons`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#enscons) | [`flit_core`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#flit) | [`hatchling`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#hatch) | [`pdm-pep517`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#pdm) | [`poetry-core`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#poetry) | [`setuptools`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#easy-install) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Supports] [0.28.0+](https://github.com/dholth/enscons/blob/master/CHANGES#:%7E:text=Update%20editables%20for,660) | [image: Supports] [3.4+](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#version-3-4) | [image: Supports] [0.3+](https://github.com/pypa/hatch/commit/eef7d0c#diff-349bd6b94a1514449b8e77147675ad04398507e47265ad1c176b718347208c55R42-R61) | [image: Supports] [0.8.0+](https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm-pep517/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-v080-2021-06-29) | [image: Supports] [1.0.8+](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/releases/tag/1.0.8) | [image: Supports] [64.0.0+](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v64-0-0) |

Comment: Please explain what a `backend` is. Is `pip` a backend or a frontend? How does it relate?  Where do those backends come from? Which backend is used by which frontend?

Comment: @Pynchia
These terms are [defined by PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#terminology-and-goals). In short, a _frontend_ is a tool that can initiate the build or installation process and a _backend_ is a packaging library that does the actual building. `pip` is Python's default frontend and `setuptools` is a default backend.

Most other packaging tools split themselves into a frontend and a backend. Each backend and frontend may have its own features, but `pyproject.toml` support makes them compatible with each other.

Answer (score 155):

Yes, `pyproject.toml` is the specified file format of [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) which contains the build system requirements of Python projects.

This solves the build-tool dependency chicken and egg problem, i.e. `pip` can read `pyproject.toml` and what version of `setuptools` or `wheel` one may need.

If you need a `setup.py` for an editable install, you could use a shim in `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the shim! So it seems that the `pyproject.toml` is *almost* a replacement for `setup.py` and developers are expected to use *both* so that the project can be installed in editable state? Weirdly, I have been using `setup.py` for few years in various small projects and never had a need to remove a "chicken and egg problem".

Comment: This is also useful if you aren't use setuptools, for example [flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rationale.html) or [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)

Comment: I'm confused... what does pip have to do with building? Isn't pip just for installing dependencies?

Comment: @Shannon  To build a Project you may need to install at least some abstract dependencies to execute the build system. pip can act as a installer backend, while `pip wheel target-dir` pip is acting as a build frontend and with `pip install lxml==2.4.0` as a integration fronted, see [PEP517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/)

Comment: A common chicken and egg problem is building an extension with pybind11. `setup.py` needs to add `pybind11.get_include()` to the compiler flags, but can't do that unless `pybind11` is installed. And if this is specified as a dependency in `setup.py` ...

Answer (score 127):

`pyproject.toml` is the new [unified Python project settings file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) that [replaces `setup.py`](https://snarky.ca/what-the-heck-is-pyproject-toml/).
[Editable installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install) still need a `setup.py`: `import setuptools; setuptools.setup()`

To use `pyproject.toml`, run `python -m pip install .`

Then, if the project is using [`poetry`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) instead of `pip`, you can install dependencies (into `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs`) like this:

```
poetry install
```

And then run dependencies like [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/):

```
poetry run pytest tests/
```

And [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com) (uses `.pre-commit-config.yaml`):

```
poetry run pre-commit install
poetry run pre-commit run --all-files
```

Comment: In what sense is `setup.py` non-editable?

Comment: @Dave An *editable install* is an installation where the installed files are symlinks pointing back to the source directory.  This is particularly useful for developers, so they don't need to reinstall the package every time they change a line of code.

Comment: what if I need to run `arch -arm64 pip3 install psycopg2 --no-binary :all:` AND update pyproject.toml?

Comment: @Ren https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043037/819417 with `poetry update` instead of `pip install`

Comment: @CeesTimmerman yeah but that doesn't add the `arch -arm64` command nor the `--no-binary :all:` options.

Comment: `PIP_NO_BINARY="psycopg2"` but that's not needed according to https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/365#issuecomment-537798177 and deprecated in 1.1.0 says the thread with a workaround of editing `poetry.lock`: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1316#issuecomment-996865695
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1286 mentions a precompiled version but at this point i'd drop stagnant Poetry or use `asyncpg`.

Comment: Followup question, sorry if it is ignorant: I am working on adding Poetry to a large existing project and was very confused about Poetry and editable installs for a while. However, I was reminded by a coworker that development ought to be done in a virtual environment. If we assume that is true, why would a Poetry user ever need an editable install? When I make changes to package code between calls to `poetry run python3 xxx`, the changes are observed in the output. That seems sufficiently editable to me? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @retsigam That should be a separate question, but it seems that [`pip install -e`](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/t3p3ub/poetry_has_officially_fixed_permanently_included/) does the same as `poetry install` now, except for possible package list updates i don't care about as the default tool should suffice.

Comment: Apparently, setup.py isn't needed anymore for editable installs. https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html

Answer (score 22):

Answering this part only, as the rest has nicely been explained by others:

> How would one install a project with `pyproject.toml` in an editable state?

#### Solution

Since the release of poetry-core v1.0.8 in Feb 2022 you can do this:

a) you need this entry in your `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.8"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

b) run:

```
pip install -e .
```

#### Sources

- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/34#issuecomment-1054626460

Comment: Update 2022: PEP 660 is implemented in `pip` (from 21.3.0) and some backends, e.g. `flit`. However no progress in `setuptools`.

Comment: Note that the `poetry install` command already makes an editable install by default, which is also explained in the issue you've linked.

Comment: The PR in poetry seems to be merged already. Does this means that editable versions with poetry do not require this workaround anymore?

Answer (score 3):

pyproject.toml can declare the files in your python package and all the metadata for it that will show in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).

A tool like [flit](https://github.com/pypa/flit) can process the pyproject.toml file into a package that can be uploaded to PyPi or installed with pip.

Other tools use pyproject.toml for other purposes.   For example, [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org) stores information about where to find and how to run tests, and instructions to pytest about modifying pythonpath (sys.path) before running the tests.  Many IDEs can use this to help developers conveniently run tests.

Comment: your link to pytest erroneously links to flit.