# How to build a C extension in keeping with PEP 517, i.e. with pyproject.toml instead of setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I want to build a C extension for CPython. I could do it traditionally with a `setup.py` file. However, for the reasons mentioned in PEP 517, I would prefer a declarative approach using a `pyproject.toml`. I understand that `setuptools` is the only build backend that can build C extensions on all relevant platforms. In fact, I am unaware of any backend capable of building C extensions at all alongside the outdated `distutils`.

Against this background, a common `setup.py` would look like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
kwargs = dict(
    name='mypackage',
    # more metadata
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('mypackage.mymodule', ['lib/mymodule.c',
                                         'lib/mypackage.c',
                                         'lib/myalloc.c'],
                  include_dirs=['lib'],
                  py_limited_api=True)])

setup(**kwargs)
```

Now, the challenge is to put the above into a `pyproject.toml` plus a `setup.cfg`.

The `setuptools` docs suggest a `pyproject.toml` like this:

```toml
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools >=52.0",
        'wheel >= 0.36']
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

See

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_meta.html and
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#declarative-config

Further, the actual metadata should go into `setup.cfg`. However, I haven't found any explanation on how to translate the `ext_modules` kwarg, in particular the `Extension()` call, into `setup.cfg` syntax.

Comment: So what is blocking? What is your current status? Any error message?

Comment: My status is: blocked by lack of documentation on how to declare the C extension in the setup.cfg file. I thought about a [build_ext] section, but didn't find any docs either. So I guess I am a few steps away from attempting a build.

Comment: Looks like it is not supported (yet): https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2220

Answer (score 15):

`pyproject.toml` is not strictly meant to replace `setup.py`, but rather to ensure its correct execution if it's still needed (see [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#source-trees) and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472800/11725753)):

> Where the `build-backend` key exists, this takes precedence and the source tree follows the format and conventions of the specified backend (as such no `setup.py` is needed **unless the backend requires it**). Projects may still wish to include a `setup.py` for compatibility with tools that do not use this spec.

While `setuptools` plans to move everything from a script into a config file, [it's not always possible](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata):

> There are two types of metadata: static and dynamic.
>
> - Static metadata (`setup.cfg`): guaranteed to be the same every time. This is simpler, easier to read, and avoids many common errors, like encoding errors.
> - Dynamic metadata (`setup.py`): possibly non-deterministic. Any items that are dynamic or determined at install-time, **as well as extension modules** or extensions to `setuptools`, need to go into `setup.py`.
>
> Static metadata should be preferred and dynamic metadata should be used only as an escape hatch when absolutely necessary.

In fact, `setuptools` [will still use an imaginary `setup.py` if it doesn't exist](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects).

**Note:** [Since version 61.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v61-0-0) `setuptools` allows to [specify project metadata and other configuration options in `pyproject.toml` file](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html). Its use looks more attractive as this file has another, more useful function and allows to specify most of the metadata in standardized, tool-agnostic way.

---

With that being said, if you want to stick as much as possible to a static way, you could move everything you can into `pyproject.toml` file and leave the rest in `setup.py` for now:

**`pyproject.toml`**

```toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mypackage"
# more metadata
```

**`setup.py`**

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup_args = dict(
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(
            'mypackage.mymodule',
            ['lib/mymodule.c', 'lib/mypackage.c', 'lib/myalloc.c'],
            include_dirs = ['lib'],
            py_limited_api = True
        )
    ]
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

Comment: Does this still work?

Comment: @not2qubit Yes, it does. The [setuptools documentation suggests the same](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html).

Comment: This look a little cleaner than Chandan's answer.

Comment: I got this to work, and much better when using a `src` structure, instead of a flat structure. The only thing that doesn't work is asking for a different compiler when trying to use `python -m build ...` or `pip install ..`. Only thing that works in the *deprecated* method of `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32`.

Comment: I managed to get the build under control by copying the (global) `distutils.cfg` to `setup.cfg`, where I specify the compiler. Then the build is done using `build` package, and then `python -m build -n -w` && `pip install <path-to>.whl`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a hack which can be used to build ext with `pyproject.toml` without depending on `setup.py`

**`pyproject.toml`**

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ["_custom_build"]

[tool.setuptools.cmdclass]
build_py = "_custom_build.build_py"
```

**`_custom_build.py`**

```py
from setuptools import Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py

class build_py(_build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return super().run()

    def initialize_options(self):
        super().initialize_options()
        if self.distribution.ext_modules == None:
            self.distribution.ext_modules = []

        self.distribution.ext_modules.append(
            Extension(
                "termial_random.random",
                sources=["termial_random/random.c"],
                extra_compile_args=["-std=c17", "-lm"],
            )
        )
```

Comment: Isn't there an issue with the `_custom_build` module being actually pip-installed? Instead of this module being available only during the "build time", it is always available and importable even at "run time". -- Would it still work if it were removed from the list of `py-modules`? Maybe it should only be added to `MANIFEST.in` instead, so that `_custom_build` is available in the sdists but not in the wheels (so not installed).

Comment: What's the build command with this?

Comment: @sinoroc Yes, your suggestion should work. The whole point, however, is not to get rid of `setup.py`, but of any excess code execution. So this solution doesn't make much sense anyway, it just replaces `setup.py` with another `.py`.

Comment: @not2qubit As with any `pyproject.toml`-style project, you should use the [`build` tool](https://github.com/pypa/build) or any other PEP 517 build frontend.

Comment: @evgenko423 I agree. There does not seem to be much of a point in removing `setup.py` and putting the custom command in a different file instead. There does not seem to be any gain. But technically, it still seems correct, even though (again) I do not know in which case one would want to do that (instead of `setup.py`).

Comment: This method now works for me after having installed all the (7 GB+) Desktop build tools for MS Visual Studio, before it would not work. However, it seem that the compiler args are completely ignored, as i also tried this with MinGW compiler before being *forced* back to the MS/VS universe of madness.