# What is the difference between pyproject.toml and the setup_requires argument of setuptools.setup()

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

`pyproject.toml` (from PEP 518) is for "the build system requirements".

The `setup_requires` argument of `setuptools.setup()` is for "other distributions required for the setup script to run".

I'm having a hard time understanding what the practical difference between these is (if any)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is pyproject.toml file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983756/what-is-pyproject-toml-file-for)

Comment: Think that you need to import a dependency in `setup.py` — you cannot install it using `setup_requires` because `setup()` is called after the import and the import would fail. `pyproject.toml` is interpreted before `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` so it can install build time dependencies that will be imported in `setup.py`.

Comment: Yes, thank you phd, that answers my question