# Relative import statements, a billionth one

Tags: python, import

Is there a clear, simple strategy to do relative imports in Python that doesn't require creating Packages, as I would like to use them between sub-folders of my project while I develop the project?

I'm referring to relative imports, like:

```
from ..mypackage import mymodule
from ..mypackage.mymodule import mymethod
from .. import mypackage
```

Only the most simple cases of relative imports actually work. Anything else results in the error message:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Creating a package makes little sense in this context, as I am simply in need of importing relatively between sub-folders in my main project. I use `sys.path.append()` as a workaround, but that should not be necessary, and it is not portable.

There is a SO post, [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time), which addresses this problem. The main article plus 15 answers and 36 comments indicate that this issue has been around for a long time. Many very smart people have offered exotic explanations and proposed cumbersome solutions to such a simple issue.
It seems the issue revolves around where Python thinks the importing module is in the file system at the time it attempts to execute the import statements. My opinion is that Python should be able to figure out if it is and exactly where in the file hierachy that is. I'm looking for a simple way to make import statements work as expected whether the importing module is called from another module, or if it is run from an interpreter, or an IDE like Pycharm.

Comment: There are two common cases: You're importing from a system module found in `sys.path`, or you're importing from a module that's packaged with the script. Relative paths handle the second case.

Comment: Is your project properly packaged and installed?

Comment: @Barmar It shouln't make a difference, which is my point. When a .. is encountered, Python should know where it is and should look at the parent directory which, if it is a package, should deliver the requested module. Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: @juanpa What is 'properly package and installed'? That's nonsense; a program is a program. It's a main module and all of its referenced modules, classes, and functions. How it got there is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @fossildoc as in, you defined the package in a `my_package/setup.cfg` or `my_package/setup.py`  (and nowadays, with a `pyproject.toml` as well) and then did `pip install my_package`.

Comment: @juanpa I have no idea what any of that means. I wrote a program on my PC for local use only. No pip, no install, no packaging for distribution, etc. None of this has anything to do with my post. A package is a directory which contains modules and a __init__.py file (which doesn't seem to be necessary lately). Pip has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @fossildoc yea, see, then you need to add the package to the path. If you *don't* want to actually package your package, then you can try to set the `PYTHONPATH='/path/to/package'`

Comment: You, on one hand, complain that `sys.path.append` is *not portable*, you know what *would make everything portable*? Actually packaging your package

Comment: @juanpa I know about PYTHONPATH. That is needed only when there are no other hints as to where a requested module resides. It is not necessary when relative imports are used. If PYTHONPATH were necessary, then relative import notatoin would be completely redundant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not asking any programming problem. The OP knows the solution to the problem and is just stating that there shouldn't be a need for workarounds, etc. This isn't really answerable here on Stack Overflow and is something that should be posted on the relevant places where such discussion about Python happens.

Comment: I'm not sure what you find so exotic about `__package__`. Just like relative paths resolve against the current working directory, relative imports resolve against the current package. The "no known parent package" means `__package__` is set to `None` (you attempt to use a relative import from a script) or it is set to `''` (you attempt to use a relative import from a top-level module). See PEP 366 more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some SO users may think that this question is "opinion-based" and try to close it. I think this is a valid question, because it asks of a clear programming issue with no clear solution.
I will therefore give you my technical answer, by no means intended to be "the most appropriate solution".

I think that **relative imports in Python are badly designed and best avoided, unless solutions are taken to make them intuitive**<sup>1, 2</sup>.

My **personal solutions** are either one of the following.

#### 1. Use a dedicated package

If you are ok with an extra package, there are several targeting this issue. In a nutshell, these are just wrappers of `sys.path.append`, but making it more portable, and allowing "relative imports" to work as you would expect. Examples of such packages include [`importmonkey`](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey) and [`ultraimport`](https://github.com/ronny-rentner/ultraimport).

Taking a folder structure like:

```
root
├─ subfolder
│   └─ subscript.py
└─ rootscript.py
```

With `rootscript.py`:

```py
def somerootfunction():
    print("I'm a function at the root of the project")
```

You can use [`importmonkey`](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey) in `subscript.py` to call `somerootfunction()`:

```py
from importmonkey import add_path; add_path("../")
from rootscript import somerootfunction

somerootfunction()
```

Not ideal, but it works. Linting and debugging are retained. I find it much simpler, effective, and easy to communicate than "the *appropriate solutions*"<sup>2</sup>.

#### 2. Use symbolic links

**Alternatively**, *in limited cases and after having considered a folder restructure or the other alternatives*<sup>2</sup>, use **symbolic links**.
You can link an entire parent folder placing a link in some sub folder, so Python can finally access it. If you use a **relative path** during the link creation, this will also make the project portable. Editing the linked code files by opening the items from the link will simply modify the source files. Finally, [Git treats symbolic links as just another file that points to a location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/3873799), so there is no issue with versioning.

The main downside is that this solution is OS-dependent (i.e. a symbolic link created on Linux won't be read as one if you open your project in Windows). There aren't workarounds to this, as far as I'm aware. It hasn't been an issue for my projects.

- On Linux, I personally use [vscode-symlink](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anbuselvan.vscode-symlink) to make it easy from VSCode. Otherwise just use `ln -s source_path destination_path`.
- On Windows, you can use `mklink`. If you're using it from a non-cmd terminal (e.g. the VSCode terminal) remember to [prepend `cmd /c`](https://superuser.com/a/98480/327009) before using it. E.g., if I'm in the sub-folder and I want to link to a parent folder file, `cmd /c mklink rootscript.py ..\rootscript.py`.
  You can link to a directory [with the `/D` argument](https://superuser.com/a/1766340/327009).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The fact that there's lots of confusion on this matter is undeniable. This is proven by: A) the abundance of StackOverflow  with no clear answer (e.g. [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)), Reddit and various website posts on the subject, many proposing conflicting solutions (of which I'm listing some examples in **note 2** below). Further, the confusion is proven by B) the existence of many dedicated packages targeting the issue, of which I'm listing some examples in my Solution 1.

As a personal addendum, I believe that this is a strong indication of Python's bad design when it comes to relative imports, and another proof that Python is a good and easy scripting language, but a flawed, clumsy and hard to master programming language. For my large software projects I use other languages, and if I need Python (likely e.g. when dealing with Machine Learning), I use interop methods to call separate, small Python scripts.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I'd recommend going for solution 1 (use a dedicated package) before going for other solutions. Probably, "the appropriate" solution is to create a package and installing the project with a [`pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) file, and/or using [`flit`](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/rationale.html)/[`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/). However, there is still a lot of reading and learning required to do it, and in the best case you still have to complicate your project with added files (e.g. `__init.py__`) or managing a package when you're still in development/debugging stage. Also, there is still confusion and disagreement on this solution, [due to this having replaced older standard solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472800/3873799). Others [believe](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/mjithh/comment/gtanb4i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that [pip install with editable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842303/3873799) is sufficient. Some suggest editing `PYTHONPATH`, which I think is downright bad.
I think that these solutions are viable but complicate life immensely, especially for newcomers. Some of these will actually work but introduce issues or complications with either debugging and/or linting the import source, making the programming experience far from ideal.</sup>

Comment: Finally, a well-thought-out set of solutions by a person much smarter than me, who also recognizes the legitimacy of my OP. Apostles of the BDFL who wish to sidestep the issue by closing the question are merely ostriches unwilling to acknowledge the malfeasance of Python maintainers. Thank you, @alelom; I will try your solutions, including using interop methods rather than large standalone Python programs.

Comment: @fossildoc Let me know if any of the solutions proposed worked for you, please remember to comment here once done, I'm sure it would be useful for me and others to know. Also please remember to upvote/accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: @fossildoc as predicted, my answer got downvoted without any comments. I'd rather delete this answer if it's not useful for you either, I spent time writing it and I don't want to lose reputation over it. However I think it would be useful to keep it as I know that some people would find your question and my answer to be valuable. Please consider upvoting it and accepting it, or let me know if it wasn't helpful, in which case I'll delete it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and marked the topic as complete. I also copied your entire response to a file on my PC. Don't be bullied by the SO Commandos; everyone knows about them. It's only a matter of time before a competing site appears, not run by megalomaniacal Stalinists. I'd do it myself if I wasn't up to my ears with other projects. They'll probably ban me for this comment. A pox on all their houses.