# Python project structure - no module named 'lib'

Tags: python

I have never worked on or built myself a properly structure Python codebase before. I aim to do that today.

Here's the structure I have attempted to implement:

```
My-Fancy-Project-Name
  /src
    /bin
      /binary1/main.py
      /binary2/my_binary.py
      /binary3
        my_scripy.py
        aux_file.txt
      /binaryother
        binary4.py
        binary5.py
        binary6.py
    /lib
      /lib1
        __init__.py
        lib1.py
      /libio
        __init__.py
        libio.py
      /libexception
        __init__.py
        exceptions.py
```

This structure is somewhat systems programming language inspired. It may not be a suitable project structure in the world of Python.

My reasoning for this structure is as follows:

The root directory for my whole "project" lives one level above `My-Fancy-Project-Name`. It contains all kinds of stuff, not all written in the same language, to do various things which are all related to a single project objective.

Broadly speaking this consists of:

- data collection and webscraping
- data preprocessing stages
- data analysis stages and visualization
- auxillary stuff, including some metrics visualization
- a webserver to serve preprocessed data to other external clients
- a documentation folder
- some shared stuff such as a couple of data folders containing small size data files
- a `.venv` virtual environment

Within the root directory there are other directories. One of those is called `My-Fancy-Project-Name`. (It isn't really, this is just an example name.)

- The point being: `My-Fancy-Project-Name` collects together an aggregation of python code which all relates to one part of the project. Specifically, all the code for "data collection via webscraping" is contained in this directory.

There are a number of scripts which act like executables. They perform some function. One of those is the main webscraper, others are smaller webscrapers which perform some specific function in some sense acting like a small utility. These "executables" are stored in a `bin` directory.

There is common code which is shared by each of the Python scripts ("executables"). This "library" code lives in a folder called `lib`.

Both `bin` and `lib` live in a folder called `src`. The intention is to add a `doc` folder which is adjacent to `src`.

I am running into issues where Python doesn't know how to "get to" the library folder code. This is unsurprising because I would not expect python to search any path other than the system defined paths and the current directory from where the Python script is executed.

My question is, how *should* I structure my project in a sensible way so that I can have a folder of shared library code, called `lib`, which contains sub-modules or packages(?), which can be accessed by a set of Python "executables" (scripts) contained inside a `bin` directory?

Comment: What build backend are you using in [`pyproject.toml`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62983756/11082165)? setuptools?