# Python project directory structure. ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I have attempted to follow what I believe to be a standard Python project directory structure to create a minimal working test example.

Here is the structure I am currently using.

```
python-project-test/
  .venv/...
  scripts/
    main.py
  src/
    __init__.py
    liblocal/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
```

This is what the import statement looks like in `main.py`:

```
from src.liblocal.module1 import my_function
```

I have tried to run `main.py` from the project root.

```
python3 scripts/main.py
```

Since `src` is a module (it contains an `__init__.py` file, I would have expected python to look in all adjacent directories to scripts and thus find the `src` module. This isn't working as I expected, which suggests I have misunderstood how python is expected to find the `src` module.

I have a few closely related questions:

1. Why is this not working, and what might I do to fix it?
2. Does it matter what directory I run `main.py` from? (eg: from within `scripts` vs the project root)
3. I am using a virtual environment. If I understand correctly it should be possible to set up the virtual environment so that python knows where to find the module `src` and any sub-modules. If this is correct, how do I do that?
4. Does this project follow the expected "typical" python project directory structure? If not, what have I midunderstood or done differently?

Comment: Having a `__init__.py` inside `src` isn't typical. That makes it seam like you want `src` to be the top-level package instead of `liblocal` (and if that were the case, you'd want give your package a better name). Standard practice for a src-layout project would be to add the `src` directory to your import path by installing your project to the virtual environment in editable mode.

Comment: @Brian61354270 ok thanks, that's great. What are the options regarding layouts? From your comment it sounds like the "src" approach might be one possibilty amoung a few common ones, perhaps? Finally, how do I add `src` to the venv path? I know nothing about this and it's the first I've heard of it so far

Comment: To directly address the questions, 1) likely because you haven't installed your project to the virtual environment. Make sure your `pyproject.toml` file is configured for this layout, then try running `pip install -e .` from the base directory. 2) no, once your project is installed, your package(s) can be imported from anywhere. Neither the CWD or script location will matter. 3) see (1). If you use an editable install, the `src` directory will be added to the virtual environments import path

Comment: 4) yes, this looks like a standard [src layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/)

Comment: @Brian61354270 thanks for your comments, that's all very helpful - how can I find more information about this pyproject.toml and how to install the project into the virtual env?

Comment: See [What is pyproject.toml file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62983756/11082165) and https://packaging.python.org/ (in particular the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial, and the [Writing your pyproject.toml](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) and [Packaging projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/) guides) to get started.

Comment: For configuring `pyproject.toml`, that will also depend on what build backend you use. This are quite a few to choose from, each with different scopes and feature sets. PyPA makes `setuptools`, `hatch`, `flit`. The leading third-party backend is `poetry-core`, which is part of the larger [Python poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) toolset. You should be able to pick any one to get started. Switching down the road just means editing a few lines in `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: To be able to install you project, you just need a minimal configuration in `pyproject.toml` that includes a description of how to map your source tree to import packages. What that looks like varies between build backends. In poetry, that just means configuring the `tool.poetry` table with some minimal metadata and the line `packages = [{from = "src", include = "liblocal"}]` ([docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages)). In setuptools, it means configuration the `[tool.setuptools.package-dir]` table ([docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html))

Comment: Once `pyproject.toml` is setup, you'll be able to install your project to your virtual environment interpreter simply by running `pip install -e .`. You'll then be able to `import liblocal` from anywhere while using the virtual environment.

Comment: @Brian61354270 thanks again - so poetry is a build backend. Is pip3 also a build backend? I have not used poetry before. I have of course used pip to install things previously, so using that if possible might make sense?

Comment: pip is a [build frontend](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Build-Frontend). Basically, a build frontend is the tool you interact with the name/find packages. The build backend is what determines how a project's source files get converted into an installable distribution. Every project can pick its own build backend. The downstream user gets to pick their own build frontend. The two need not be related.

Comment: Poetry is both a build frontend (the `poetry` command), integration frontend (poetry's dependency resolved and locking), and build backend (`poetry-core`). You can use poetry as a build backend without using it as your build/integration frontend (just list `poetry-core` under `build-system.build-backend`, and use `pip` on the command line).

Comment: To contextualize things a bit more, when you run `pip install xzy`, pip essentially does the following: 1) locates/downloads the source tree for `xyz`, 2) creates a temporary isolated build venv, 3) installs `xyz`'s build backend to the temporary venv, 4) invokes the build backend to create a distribution file for `xyz`, 5) installs the `xyz` distribution and deletes the temporary venv. There are some variations. E.g., if you use a editable install `pip install -e`, instead of building a distribution file, pip will just add your project's source directories to the interpreter's import path.

Answer (score 2):

Having done some searching I have managed to get to a working solution.

## Virtual Environments, setuptools, and a `pyproject.toml` file:

In summary, do the following things:

- create a Virtual Environment with `python3 -m venv .venv`
- activate it (enable the venv) `source .venv/bin/activate`

*Asside: I like to create a symlink to `.venv/bin/activate` so I can simply run `. activate` from the project root to activate my venvs.*

- install any libraries you need with `pip3 install ...`
- create a folder for your "binaries" called `bin`, put your "executable" Python scripts here
- create a folder called `src` for your library code
- for each library **module** create a directory under `src`
- add an `__init__.py` file to each library module
- add your module code for each library module
- create `pyproject.toml` in the project root (see below)
- "build" your libraries, and "install" them `pip3 install -e .` from the project root

What does all of this do?

What you are effectively doing here is moving module code out of one directory, where the python interpreter can find it, into another where it cannot. That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, except to say the project directory structure is now improved. You should have some minimal "executable" python scripts in a `bin` directory and everything else logically organized under a `src` directory.

In order for the Python interpreter to find it, what you are doing here is "installing" your library code into the active Virtual Environment using `pip3`. In order to install it, you first need to build it with `setuptools`. When you build it and install it you use the `-e` flag. This installs it using symlinks instead of the usual way, which means if you modify your code, you can use the modifications immediatly without having to run the install step again.

Hopefully that all makes sense, I only recently learned about this, so this is my best attempt to provide a straightforward explanation.

## Example `toml` file

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project_name"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My Project Description"

[tools.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

## Directory Structure

Your directory structure should look something like this:

```
project_root/
  bin/
    script1.py
    scripy2.py
    related_group_of_scripts/
      do_thing_1.py
      do_thing_2.py
  src/
    libhelper/
      __init__.py
      helper.py
    libio/
      __init__.py
      iohelper.py
    libexception/
      __init__.py
      exception_types.py
  .venv/
  pyproject.toml
```

I have included some arbitrary library names to demonstrate a possible structure.