# Please find the cause of "Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" - Error

Tags: python, pip, aiohttp

I was just trying to install aiohttp in python.
So I just typed in console like that: pip install aiohttp .
At first, the installation went well, but finally I got the following Error.

```
C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts>pip3 install aiohttp
Collecting aiohttp
  Obtaining dependency information for aiohttp from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/13/e929a6a50288e60ade3961b294d2f5aeb251b6579e4290a5397e484d0df9/aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
 ...   ...
Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (50 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
 ...   ...
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

So I tried the another one "pip install pyproject".
But I can't solve.
Please help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is pyproject.toml file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983756/what-is-pyproject-toml-file-for)

Comment: But still I can't find the solution.

Comment: The main error is following:
'Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error'

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install --no-deps aiohttp --upgrade`

Comment: @ElonMusk I've written an answer for you and I hope you'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

As of February the 1st 2024, [multidict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict) released a wheel for Python 3.12.

You can [download it here](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/#files), but it will also be updated over the coming days in the affected libraries. `aiohttp` as an example updated theirs today (02-02-2024).

**END OF EDIT**

I just had this problem and despite the other answer, `aiohttp` [does have Python 3.12 wheels](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/#files), so it should work.

This is how I solved it (for Windows using VS Code):

Download the Microsoft C++ Build Tools as provided in the link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

[image]

Click `Download Build Tools` and run it as administrator.

Accept terms and wait for it to download and install.

Select the `Individual components` pane and click off:

[image]

- Windows Universal C Runtime
- C++ Build Tools core features
- C++ 2022 Redistributable Update
- C++ CMake tools for Windows
- MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)

For Windows 10:

Windows 10 SDK (Pick newest version)

For Windows 11:

Windows 11 SDK (Pick newest version)

Click install and wait for it to finish.

Restart Windows or try to restart VS Code and rerun the `pip install aiohttp`.

Output after installing the above and running pip install:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting aiohttp
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (32 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp)
  Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (363 kB)
Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (50 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for multidict: filename=multidict-6.0.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl size=28177 sha256=0f82cc586f78a9e5c78ff9464e110da133cfe3a8636e7abf5e32b432113654e7
  Stored in directory: c:\users\m89237\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\f6\d8\ff\3c14a64b8f2ab1aa94ba2888f5a988be6ab446ec5c8d1a82da
Successfully built multidict
Installing collected packages: multidict, idna, frozenlist, attrs, yarl, aiosignal, aiohttp
Successfully installed aiohttp-3.9.3 aiosignal-1.3.1 attrs-23.2.0 frozenlist-1.4.1 idna-3.6 multidict-6.0.4 yarl-1.9.4
```

Import test:

```
PS C:\Users\m89237\OneDrive\BACKUP\Python> python
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import aiohttp
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.` So you should get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/%60)

Also please note that [aiohttp currently supports Python 3.8 - 3.10](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/) but you appear to be using Python 3.12.