# setuptools warning: Failed to find the configured license file 'L'

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, licensing, python-wheel

I am building a wheel using
`python setup.py bdist_wheel`
Basically `setuptools` library.

My project contains `LICENSE.txt` file in root directory of the repository.

#### Aim:

Properly include this particular license file in the wheel

#### Relevant Code:

```
setup(
...,
license_files='LICENSE.txt',
...
)
```

#### Error:

```
warning: Failed to find the configured license file 'L'
warning: Failed to find the configured license file 'C'
warning: Failed to find the configured license file 'N'
warning: Failed to find the configured license file 't
```

Comment: Perhaps this post answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977889/how-to-include-license-file-in-setup-py-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#metadata

Setuptools official doc states the datatype of `license_file` to be "str" and `license_files` to be list-comma

### Solution 1: Use `license_file` with `str`

```
setup(
...,
license_file='LICENSE.txt',
...
)
```

### Solution 2a: Use `license_files` with comma separated list

```
setup(
...,
license_file=LICENSE.txt,
...
)
```

### Solution 2b setup.cfg with `license_files`

I instead created a new file `setup.cfg` and upgraded my setuptools to allow it to pick up metadata from setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
license_files = <name-of-license-file>
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691876/5157515
[image]

Comment: `license_file` should indeed be a string, but you are using `license_files` in your question. This should be a list of strings, thus the error.

Comment: Using `license_file` as a `setup` argument will fail with message: `UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'license_file'`. `license_files` is ok.